# Devise: one user getting a 302 and 401 error, no idea why, correct credentials not much in the log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've got a Rails app which generally works fine, but one (that I can find) user is causing a `302` error, and they can't log in. The log looks like this:

```
Started GET "/d/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-15 05:38:14 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10.1ms (Views: 7.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
Started GET "/d/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-15 05:38:14 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10.9ms (Views: 8.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
Started GET "/" for 58.111.229.203 at 2014-12-15 05:38:20 +0000
Processing by DocumentsController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0.5ms
Started POST "/d/sign_in" for 58.111.229.203 at 2014-12-15 05:38:28 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cvyg6GWTtpd4M1klk0j6APbv4h36+a99yb9k646BRZA=", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@blank.net", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Redirected to http://appdomain.com/
Completed 302 Found in 310.2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/d/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-15 05:38:29 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10.1ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Now, the `127.0.0.1` things concern me since this is a production environment, but it might be just a service (Pingdom) ensuring the app is still up. Nevertheless, this user can't log in and I can't figure it out. No other users are affected that I know of, and the user has everything they need to be able to log in. No detailed errors are in the log (like missing resources or similar), it just hangs when they log in. Any help would be great.

**Update**

Here's `DocumentsController` (the relevant parts):

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper
  include DocumentsHelper
  include ServerHelper

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @documents = current_user.documents.includes(:template).includes(:user)
                             .includes(:pdf_result).created.page(params[:page])
                             .per(10)
    @categories = current_user.brand.templates.all.group_by(&:category)
    @assets = AssetResources.new(current_user)
  end

  ...
```

Changing this user to an administrator does not fix the problem. I guess `ApplicationController` is relevant too, and this is it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :check_mode

  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to documents_url, alert: exception.message
  end

  helper_method :current_user, :authorised_user

  hide_action :current_user

  def mode
    @mode = Mode.first
  end

  def check_mode
    flash.now[:alert] = mode.messages unless mode.all_online
  end

  private

  def user_activity
    current_user.try :touch
  end

  def authorised_user
    @authorised_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

**UPDATE** The credentials are correct, when that email address and an incorrect password are entered I get a bad credentials message. The correct credentials just hangs.

Comment: `DocumentsController#index` -- `Unauthorized` seems something related to permissions for some users

Comment: Can you post session and documents controller? If you have some before filter on document controllers index action then post that as well

Comment: `SessionsController` is Devise's default. Will post `DocumentsController` though.

Answer (score 1):

Check

1. Whether this "admin@blank.net" user exists in database.
2. You are providing correct credentials.

Because when sign in fails, devise internally performs redirection and 302 is  HTTP response status code for URL redirection.

In the database, ensure whether this user exists and you are providing the right credentials.

Comment: The credentials are correct, when that email address and an incorrect password are entered I get a bad credentials message. The correct credentials just hangs.

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is old**. But just in case someone has the same problem, as I just did, here is what fixed it for me:

In

> config/initializers/session_store.rb

change

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'my_secure_session', httponly: false, secure: true
```

to

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'my_session'
```

**Why I had this problem in the first place:** I copied a running Rails 4 server with SSL and booted it up in dev mode without SSL. Commenting out `force_ssl` in `application_controller.rb` allowed me to start the server without ssl but left me with the 302 and 401 error and a redirect back to the sign-in page (without notification).